# Connect to LocalHost Database via PHP from exterior

Tags: php, localhost

I have 2 PC and both are on different LAN.
What I am trying to do is to Connect to LocalHost database of PC1 via PHP from PC2.

Something like this:

```
$db_host = 'MY_EXTERNAL_IP';
$db_user = '***';
$db_pass = '***';
$db_name = '***';

// CONNECT TO DB
$link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die('Error DB');
mysqli_select_db($link,$db_name);
```

What I've tried already:

- PORT 80 is open on PC1.
- If I access via browser External IP of PC1 I get www folder
- I've added to PhpMyAdmin user with "Any Host /%"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL by default runs on port 3306, so if you want to connect to MySQL you need to open up that port.

Comment: so simple, yes it's work now. Thanks for your quick reply